# I want to print the sequence in line with the format ...How?

Tags: python

okay, I've figured out how to make the sequence result in one line, now I have to add a str...

here is the expected output:

Enter n: 10

Fibonacci numbers = 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55

here is my code:

```
n = input("Enter n: ")

def fib(n):
    cur = 1
    old = 1
    i = 1
    while (i < n):
        cur, old, i = cur+old, cur, i+1
    return cur

for i in range(10):
    print("Fibonacci numbers = ")
    print(fib(i), end=" ")
```

here is the output that I want to fix:

Enter n: 10

Fibonacci numbers =  1 Fibonacci numbers =  1 Fibonacci numbers =  2 Fibonacci numbers =  3 Fibonacci numbers =  5 Fibonacci numbers =  8 Fibonacci numbers =  13 Fibonacci numbers =  21 Fibonacci numbers =  34 Fibonacci numbers =  55

I'm still learning python independently, Thank you to those who'll take time to answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want `"Fibonacci numbers: "` to print out on each loop iteration, remove it from the loop body.

```
print("Fibonacci numbers = ")

for i in range(10):
    print(fib(i), end=" ")
```

To do the least calculation, it is more efficient to have a `fib` function generate a list of the first `n` Fibonacci numbers.

```
def fib(n):
  fibs = [0, 1]
  for _ in range(n-2):
    fibs.append(sum(fibs[-2:]))
  return fibs
```

We know the first two Fibonacci numbers are `0` and `1`. For the remaining count we can add the sum of the last two numbers to the list.

```
>>> fib(10)
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

You can now:

```
print('Fibonacci numbers = ', end='')
print(*fib(10), sep=' ', end='\n')
```

Answer (score -2):

```
n = input("Enter n: ")

def fib(n):
    cur = 1
    old = 1
    i = 1
    while (i < n):
        cur, old, i = cur+old, cur, i+1
    return cur

print("Fibonacci numbers:")
fib_list = list()
for i in range(int(n)):
    fib_list.append(str(fib(i)))

print(' '.join(fib_list))
```

Comment: This answer would be improved with elaboration. What was wrong with the OP's code? How does this fix it? As it stands, it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Here is the expected output:
Enter n: 10
Fibonacci numbers = 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55
Enter n: 5
Fibonacci numbers = 1 1 2 3 5